# Сравнение объектов с разными типами

Tags: java, json, парсер

Доброго времени суток. Хочу распарсить вот такой [json](http://ideone.com/vDmcRX)-файл.

Сам код для этого дела:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class JSONtest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        JSONtest jsonTest = new JSONtest();

        Object ads[] = jsonTest.getAd();
        Integer noneAds = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <ads.length; i++) {
            if (ads[i].equals(noneAds)) {
                System.out.println("Bingo");
            }
        }
    }

    public Object[] getAd() throws Exception {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/TAP/src/main/resources/vk.json"));
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        Object [] ads = new Object[7];

        try {

            JsonObject jsonResp = (JsonObject) parser.parse(bufferedReader);
            JsonArray postsList = (JsonArray) jsonResp.get("response");
            JsonObject unicPost = null;
            JSONObject jsonObject;

            for (int i = 1; i < postsList.size(); i++) {
                unicPost = (JsonObject) postsList.get(i);
                ads[i] = unicPost.get("marked_as_ads");
                System.out.println("Ads from sub " + ads[i]);
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        return ads;
    }
}
```

В main'e хочу сравнить полученные данные из метода getAds со значением 0 типа Integer, но так как они разного типа в результате получается false, там где должно быть true; Пытался скастовать, но всегда вылетала ClassCastException. Что можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Вы используете метод `public JsonElement get(String memberName)`.

У вас все верно написано, но значения корректнее сохранять в `JsonElement` при начитке, а точнее в массив `JsonElement[]`
То есть так:

```
JsonElement[] ads = new JsonElement[7];
```

Тогда начитка в цикле останется такой же как у вас.
Далее, массив `JsonElement[] json` вы можете конвертировать методом `JsonElement.getAsInt()`.
То есть так:

```
int variable = ads[i].getAsInt();
```

**Вариант 2**

Или сразу сохраняйте значения в массив `int[] ads` через метод `.getAsInt()`.
То есть так:

```
...
ads[i] = unicPost.get("marked_as_ads").getAsInt();
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Зачем записывать в массив JSON данные, если можно их превратить в строку.
Попробуйте так:

```
ads[i] = unicPost.get("marked_as_ads").getAsString();
```

Массив при этом объявите как String[].

А дальше уже, если нужно обязательно сравнить с Integer, то можете к строке применить Integer.parseInt(String s) и получить из строки число.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120882/gson-jelement-getasstring-vs-jelement-tostring

Кстати, есть метод getAsInt(). Так что можно сразу получать число. Только в Вашем файле не все данные числовые. Строка в этом смысле как-то универсальнее.

https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте воспользоваться методом:

```
int getInt (String name)
```

вместо:

```
Object get (String name)
```

То есть будет вот так:

```
ads[i] = unicPost.getInt("marked_as_ads");
```

Соответственно, придется поменять тип массива на `int[]`.

Далее можно работать с примитивами и сравнить их оператором `==`.